# Firestore Storage rules to block all folders but certain?

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am trying to set rules that will allow *only users* to create and update folders in this path: `UsersMedia/folderName` , where `folderName` is the `userId` .

Then I would like to ***not*** allow uploads to any other path in the Storage other then this.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
  
    // first rule
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if false;
      allow delete: if false;
    }

    match /UsersMedia/{userId} {
      allow create, update: if (request.auth.uid == userId) && resource.size < 25000 * 1024;  //25Mb;
      allow delete:if false;
      allow read;
    }
```

This works only if i set the first rule to allow write, if I remove the first rule it won't work at all.

Also, the rule of the size and the userId just won't take place, so i can upload files larger than the max.

What's happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the first rule will take over the other rules.
So I removed it.

Then I had a mistake and I fixed it with :

```
if (request.auth.uid == userId) && request.resource.size < 25 * 1024 * 1024;
```

To limit file size.
Now it all works.